# Filter array of objects based on the input passed: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects with the following structure

```
arr = [ { name: "abc" , items: ["itemA","itemB","itemC"], days :138} ,
        { name: "def" , items: ["itemA1","itemB2","itemC1"], days :157} ,
        { name: "hfg" , items: ["itemAN","itemB7","itemC7"], days :189} ]
```

This array needs to be filtered based on the search input passed. I was able to achieve the same for the `name` , where days is not getting filtered.

Also can someone help how to search across `items` array too so it filters the rows based on input passed

This is what I have tried

```
  handleSearch = (arr, searchInput) => {
    let filteredData= arr.filter(value => {
      return (
        value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.days.toString().includes(searchInput.toString())
      );
    });
    console.log(filteredData);
    //this.setState({ list: filteredData });
  }
```

Comment: I assume you meant to write `value.days.toString().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())`?

Comment: but days is a number , so trying to run toString on both

Comment: Filtering the inner array follows a similar logic to what you are already doing, you should filter `value.items`

Comment: That's beside the point, the problem is you are testing if `days` includes `days`, which is nonsense. Anyway, just use `[item.name, item.items.join(','), item.days].join(',')` to get a comma separated string containing all the strings and the days, then use `includes()` on that

Comment: Got it didnt see that, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @li97 did fixing that typo solve the issue or does the issue still stand?

Comment: Even shorter: `return Object.values(value).toString().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())`

Comment: it should iterate through the entire array of objects and return the matching rows. the structure is mentioned in the question

Comment: @ChrisG I wouldn't go with that suggestion because in that case, searching with `"A,i"` erroneously returns the first element.

Comment: True, but: 1) who's going to put a comma inside a search term 2) OP can remove commas from the search term first 3) or use an obscure character instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and then perform the same kind of match that you've already done :

> The **some()** method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
  handleSearch = (arr, searchInput) => {
    const filteredData = arr.filter(value => {
      const searchStr = searchInput.toLowerCase();
      const nameMatches = value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr);
      const daysMatches = value.days.toString().includes(searchStr);
      const oneItemMatches = value.items.some(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr));

      return nameMatches || daysMatches || oneItemMatches;
    });
    console.log(filteredData);
    //this.setState({ list: filteredData });
  }
```

Comment: what about find method?

Comment: The `find` method is for when you want to retrieve an array value. If you use the `find` method with the function `item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr)`, it will return the first element in the array that matches this predicate

Answer (score 1):

As your search value can apply to all fields in your data array, you can combine the values together in one array (row by row) and perform the search in one place.

To do that, I've provided a snippet below that will filter the original array checking each object's values after the transformations. These involve using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the object in an array, since this array is nested, we can make use of [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten it into just the strings and numbers, finally call [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if one of the values partially includes the search value (after they've both been lowercase-d).

```js
const arr = [
    { name: "abc" , items: ["itemA","itemB","itemC"], days: 138 },
    { name: "def" , items: ["itemA1","itemB2","itemC1"], days: 157 },
    { name: "hfg" , items: ["itemAN","itemB7","itemC7"], days: 189 }
];

const handleSearch = (arr, searchInput) => (
    arr.filter((obj) => (
        Object.values(obj)
              .flat()
              .some((v) => (
                  `${v}`.toLowerCase().includes(`${searchInput}`.toLowerCase())
              ))
    ))
);

console.log('"A1" =>', JSON.stringify(handleSearch(arr, 'A1')));
console.log('189 =>', JSON.stringify(handleSearch(arr, 189)));
console.log('"nope" =>', JSON.stringify(handleSearch(arr, 'nope')));
```

***NOTE:*** This approach has one obvious flaw, it will seach through numbers as strings, meaning that providing `89` as the search value will still return the second element.

Comment: what about find method?

Comment: Unlike [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will only return the first found element (if any). If that's what you want, then you can just replace that call.